# Why stringsasFactors= FALSE is used in this R code?

Tags: r

1.In this R code why stringsAsFactors = FALSE is used ?

```
       # Create the data frame.
         emp.data <- data.frame(
         emp_id = c (1:5), 
         emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
        salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 

        start_date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05- 11","2015-03-27")),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
# Print the data frame.         
        print(emp.data)
```

Comment: see `?data.frame` If you don't know what arguments mean. There you'll see the line `stringsAsFactors: logical: should character vectors be converted to factors?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the names of the employees `emp.date$emp_name` will be a character vector, instead of a factor.
I'd advise you to read more about [factors](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html) to see why this can matter.